# Grouping by date, slow query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to group each `app` by the amount of `conversations` that occured on each day for some period of time.

This is my query so far, but it runs pretty slow and I'd like to speed it up a bit. Any ideas?

```
with grouping as (
    SELECT a.id, d.date, count(c.id)
    FROM (
        select to_char(date_trunc('day', (current_date - offs)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date 
        FROM generate_series(0, 7) AS offs
    ) d 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN apps a on true
    LEFT OUTER JOIN conversations c ON (d.date=to_char(date_trunc('day', c.started_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) and a.id = c.app_id
    GROUP BY a.id, d.date
)
select 
id,
array_agg(date) as labels,
array_agg(count) as data
from grouping
group by grouping.id
```

UPDATE:

Explain plan:

```
#   QUERY PLAN
1   HashAggregate  (cost=135934.73..135937.73 rows=200 width=556) (actual time=2391.949..2392.653 rows=540 loops=1)
2     Group Key: grouping.id
3     CTE grouping
4       ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=84656.63..132964.73 rows=108000 width=25) (actual time=2206.657..2382.691 rows=4320 loops=1)
5             Group Key: a.id, (to_char(date_trunc('day'::text, ((('now'::cstring)::date - offs.offs))::timestamp with time zone), 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))
6             ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=84656.63..126214.73 rows=540000 width=25) (actual time=2206.643..2380.041 rows=4322 loops=1)
7                   Merge Cond: (((a.id)::text = (c.app_id)::text) AND ((to_char(date_trunc('day'::text, ((('now'::cstring)::date - offs.offs))::timestamp with time zone), 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text)) = (to_char(date_trunc('day'::text, c.started_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))))
8                   ->  Sort  (cost=69275.27..70625.27 rows=540000 width=21) (actual time=80.352..81.059 rows=4320 loops=1)
9                         Sort Key: a.id, (to_char(date_trunc('day'::text, ((('now'::cstring)::date - offs.offs))::timestamp with time zone), 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))
10                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 530kB
11                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..6782.75 rows=540000 width=21) (actual time=0.051..13.095 rows=4320 loops=1)
12                              ->  Function Scan on generate_series offs  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=8 loops=1)
13                              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..24.10 rows=540 width=17) (actual time=0.001..0.079 rows=540 loops=8)
14                                    ->  Seq Scan on apps a  (cost=0.00..21.40 rows=540 width=17) (actual time=0.004..0.207 rows=540 loops=1)
15                  ->  Materialize  (cost=15381.24..15870.93 rows=97938 width=28) (actual time=2103.849..2274.185 rows=97940 loops=1)
16                        ->  Sort  (cost=15381.24..15626.08 rows=97938 width=28) (actual time=2103.843..2255.284 rows=97940 loops=1)
17                              Sort Key: c.app_id, (to_char(date_trunc('day'::text, c.started_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD'::text))
18                              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2928kB
19                              ->  Seq Scan on conversations c  (cost=0.00..4917.38 rows=97938 width=28) (actual time=0.016..83.664 rows=97940 loops=1)
20    ->  CTE Scan on grouping  (cost=0.00..2160.00 rows=108000 width=556) (actual time=2206.660..2385.291 rows=4320 loops=1)
21  Planning time: 0.835 ms
22  Execution time: 2420.991 ms
```

Comment: Post an EXPLAIN PLAN for this.

Comment: forgot that, done now

Comment: Join dates to dates not strings. And that `left outer join ... on true` is really a cross/inner join, right? I doubt that's messing up the optimizer but I don't think I would write it that way.

Comment: I see you're joining on truncated dates so that may not actually help unless postgres knows that the order is preserved. I have limited experience on that platform.

Comment: as pointed out by @shawnt00 you have a cross join. Additionaly there isn't a where clause in your 'grouping' query so 2420 ms seems exceptionally good timing for this!

Comment: Actually you could limit the results on `conversation` to the date window you need. That would probably be a huge improvement. Not sure if better to do that in the join condition or as a derived table/cte.

Comment: hmm, not sure I understand. Could you provide an example? Pardon by ignoreance, I'm fairly new to DBs

Comment: @e4c5 isnt the `where` clause in the join?